# Ruby on Rails - Get records from grandchild table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have 3 tables like so (This is just a simplified example of what my table actually is):

Table #1 is titled **Parent**, and its only got two fields: `ID` and `Name`.

Humans has many children. Table #2 is therefore **Childrens** and its got `parent_id` and other unimportant fields.

Childrens has many friends. Table #3 is **Friends** and its got `children_id` and other unimportant fields.

Basically, given only the `parent_id` which let's say is 1, I want to return all values from the **Friends** table such that they are the friends of that single parent's children. I guess I'd have to iterate through the **Childrens** tables and get all `children_id` where `parent_id` = 1. And than I'd iterate through **Friends** and match on the previously collected `children_id`. Can someone show me if there's a good way of doing this in ruby on rails. I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `has_many :friends, through: :children`

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, through: :children
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :friends, dependent: :destroy
end

class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :child
end
```

Then you can access all friends like this

```
parent.friends
```